# Play digits pressed in numpad using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

When I press the numbers in numpad I need to play the wave files for the number pressed.

I used the following code

```
~Numpad1::SoundPlay, 1.wav, wait
return

~Numpad2::SoundPlay, 2.wav , wait
return

~Numpad3::SoundPlay, 3.wav, wait
return
```

and it is playing fine when I press each digit alone. But when I press 123 in sequence I can hear only last wave ( so when 123 is pressed I can hear only 3.wav). I need to hear "one two three" in sequence, is there any way for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used an array as a buffer to capture the inputs. Then, I had the script take the first element of the array, use it in a switch to determine which sound to play, and then remove that first element that we were using in order to move on to the next sound in the buffer. If what I just said doesn't make much sense, the code itself will prob be easier to understand.

Here is the code:

```
#SingleInstance Force

Buffer:=[]
Loop{
    
    Loop 1{
        tempVar := Buffer[A_Index]
        Buffer.Remove(A_Index)
    }
    if(tempVar){
        switch tempVar
        {
        Case 1:
            SoundPlay, 1.wav, wait
            tempVar:=0
        Case 2:
            SoundPlay, 2.wav, wait
            tempVar:=0
        Case 3:
            SoundPlay, 3.wav, wait
            tempVar:=0
        Default:
        }
        
    }
    
}


~Numpad1::Buffer.Push(1)
~Numpad2::Buffer.Push(2)
~Numpad3::Buffer.Push(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the use of the inner Loop (Loop 1). When I put code inside without Loop it works just as fine. anyway it is only running once, why you put it ?

Comment: In order to get the first element of the array, I wasn't able to use `Buffer[0]`/`Buffer[1]` for some reason. So, I went to the docs and saw that all of the examples I found of retrieving values from an array used a Loop's index variable in order to specify what member of the array to pull out. So, I just set the loop to run once so that the `A_Index` would just refer to the first element of the array. There probably is a better way to go about it, but that was the quickest solution I found at the time.

Comment: ok, for me it working without inner loop. I will post my code as a different answer. (also modified your code to make it shorter)

Comment: Yeah, that's a good observation on your part. I recently [after this post] updated my version of AHK, so it might have just been an issue with an older version of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified code of @Spyre to make it little shorter. Given below is the full script

```
#SingleInstance Force

;place all the wav files in same folder as this script. waves should be like 1.wav, 2.wav... wave for zero should be renamed as 99.wav 


Buffer:=[]
Loop{
    tempVar := Buffer[1]

    if(tempVar){
           
            SoundPlay, %tempVar%.wav, wait
            tempVar:=0
            Buffer.Remove(1)       
    }
    
}


~Numpad1::Buffer.Push(1)
~Numpad2::Buffer.Push(2)
~Numpad3::Buffer.Push(3)
~Numpad4::Buffer.Push(4)
~Numpad5::Buffer.Push(5)
~Numpad6::Buffer.Push(6)
~Numpad7::Buffer.Push(7)
~Numpad8::Buffer.Push(8)
~Numpad9::Buffer.Push(9)
~Numpad0::Buffer.Push(99) 

;To stop playing if too many keys are pressed at once
~*Escape::
Buffer:=[]
return
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundPlay.htm#Remarks):

> If a file is playing and the current script plays a second file, the first file will be stopped so that the second one can play. On some systems, certain file types might stop playing even when an entirely separate script plays a new file.

So sounds like making separate scripts for your hotkeys is the only easy solution you can try.
More advanced solutions would include more manually using internal Windows (or external) functions to play sounds with more control.
E.g. maybe use the [Run command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) to launch audio files in a sound player. I'd say any decent sound player can play a sound from commandline parameters. And likely can do it even without you seeing any sound player pop up on your screen. (If not I guess it could be manually hidden as well)

EDIT:
Might've misunderstood the question, my answer was for playing multiple sounds at the same time.